# Is the Freyd-Mitchell Embedding theorem necessary?

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

The famous Freyd-Mitchell theorem states that any small abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ has an exact fully faithful functor in $R$-Mod for some ring $R$. The main motivation i've seen for the (lengthy) proof of this theorem, is that it allows to prove statements about small diagrams in $\mathcal{A}$ by proving them for modules over a ring: for example, we can deduce that the Snake lemma holds in every abelian category, and hence we deduce the existence of the long exact sequence in (co)homology.
However, there is a proof of the snake lemma for abelian categories that does not rely on the FM embedding. See for example Lemma 12.1.1 in "Categories and Sheaves" by Kashiwara and Schapira.

My question is the following: are there any general statements about abelian categories (such as the snake lemma) that we can only prove by passing to $R$-Modules, or whose only known proofs are by using the FM embedding? Is, in this sense, the Freyd-Mitchell Embedding necessary?

Comment: No, it is definitely not necessary. Every proof can be done in pure category theory, and there are several, well detailed approaches. However, it makes you absolutely certain that any statement of modules with a proof of element chasing will hold in general Abelian categories.